# ID jQuery + html

Tags: jquery

Tenho duas imagens, quero que elas mudem quando:

1. O usuário passe o mouse nela, implementei com CSS, funciona bem.
2. Caso o usuário não passe o mouse na img, ao rolar a página a img muda, implementei um jquery e estou tendo dificuldades pois o código altera todas as img da página, e quero que altere uma img específica.

No html:

```
<a href="#">
  <img src="assets/images/sujo.svg" class="defaultPic" alt="Carro Sujo">
  <img src="assets/images/limpo.svg" class="altPic" alt="Carro Limpo">
</a>
```

Scritpt que estou tentando usar:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    //console.log($(document).scrollTop());
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 10) {
        $('img').attr('src', 'assets/images/limpo.svg');
    } else {
        $('img').attr('src', 'assets/images/sujo.svg');
    }
});
```

Comment: Sabe onde que pode ta seu erro? no seletor do attr, cria um id pra cada <img> e add o id das imagens no seletor, exemplo: $('#imagem1').attr('src', 'assets/images/limpo.svg');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara pega pela `classe`, já que vc já está usando uma classe na imagem vc seleciona por ela e não pela `tag img` que pega todas as tag `imgs`

Repare que agora o seletor está pegando pela classe `'.defaultPic'` e não pela tag `<img>`

```js
  $(window).scroll(function () {
      //console.log($(document).scrollTop());
      if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 10) {
          $('.defaultPic').attr('src', 'https://www.placecage.com/100/101');
      } else {
          $('.defaultPic').attr('src', 'https://www.placecage.com/100/100');
      }
  });
```

```css
body {
  height: 150vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  
<a href="#">
  <img src="https://www.placecage.com/100/100" class="defaultPic" alt="Carro Sujo">
  <img src="https://www.placecage.com/105/100" class="altPic" alt="Carro Limpo">
</a>
```